# php artisan migrate:refresh | ERROR [Laravel5]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I use Laravel 5.
when i try to refresh the migration,

INPUT:

```
  php artisan make:migrate
```

OUTPUT :

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class '****' not found
```

Even i remove that classes also.

Comment: Sorry "php artisan migrate:refresh"

Comment: Does another artisan command work?

Comment: What is the name of '*****' class?

Comment: "Todo" thats my project class.

Comment: Did you try the answer that I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

The Class "Todo", which I created record is exist in "Migration" table. Command working when I remove that record.